# Как получить выделенный текст в quill editor

Tags: vue.js, typescript

vue.js

```
<template>
...
  <div class="quill-editor-area">
    <quill-editor ref="editor" :toolbar="toolbarOptions" v-model:content="article.content"
      contentType="html" :options="editorOption":modules="modules" :disabled="disabled" />
  </div>
</template>
```

В обработчике события кастомной кнопки пытаюсь получить выделение

```
let quillEditor = this.$refs.editor as Quill;
let selection = quillEditor.getSelection();
```

В результате чего ловлю ошибку

> Uncaught TypeError: quillEditor.getSelection is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.eval

Пробовал использовать аннотацию
`@Ref("editor") editor!: Quill` - результат тот же.

Answer (score 0):

Исправил

`@Ref("editor") editor!: any`

и

```
let quillEditor = this.editor.getQuill();
let selection = quillEditor.getSelection();
```

и заработало